# debian/XFCE Virtualbox Guest on a Mac: how to use home and end keys?

Tags: debian, keyboard-shortcuts, xfce, macintosh, keyboard-layout

So I have a Mac, and rather than boot debian/XFCE directly and have to configure hardware drivers I'm using VirtualBox.

This means that my multitouch trackpad works well, and I can jump in and out of the VM very easily. I have correctly configured my keyboard mapping, including those pesky alt shortcuts, and everything.

The problem comes from the lack of `home`/`end` keys.

In OS X, I've got used to using `Ctrl+A` for `home` and `Ctrl+E` for `end`, which works everywhere (Terminal, obviously, plus TextMate, and even in forms in Chrome).

However, in XFCE this only works inside a terminal by default. I'd like to extend that shortcut (or, indeed, something like `Ctrl+Left`/`Ctrl+right`, since `Ctrl+E` seems to actually be used in applications like eclipse) to map to `home`/`end` as global keyboard shortcuts.

However, the two places where we can configure shortcuts in XFCE (Settings -> Keyboard -> Application Shortcuts, and Settings -> Window Manager -> Keyboard) the first wants a "command" to run on a particular shortcut, and the second doesn't allow you to add custom actions.

Do I want to do this in a lower level configuration, like Xorg or something, or is there a way to configure global shortcuts like this in XFCE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whoops, didn't mean for this to be an "answer your own question", but have just discovered how this works.

the Mac's `fn` key, which is needed to access the function keys even in Linux, maps `fn+left` and `fn+right` keys to `home` and `end` for you - on Mac OS this does that annoying "scroll to the top/bottom" thing, but in Linux they work like a regular `home`/`end` keys.

problem solved!

**UPDATE:**

Switching between the two "modes" of entry was driving me crazy (remember, `fn+arrows` doesn't work in OS X), so I've worked out how to get `left cmd+arrows` working in both OSs (it works by default in OS X - where `ctrl+a/e` actually do strange things in multiline inputs like stackoverflow boxes...).

It's a `~/.Xmodmap` entry, and it requires that you map the *right* `cmd` to the VirtualBox "host" key first.

```
keycode  133 = Mode_switch Meta_L Alt_L Meta_L
keycode 113 = Left NoSymbol Home
keycode 114 = Right NoSymbol End
```

(you can run `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` to apply the settings without a restart).

In Linux, this works in terminals, eclipse, everything (presumably only when X is running.)

If you're having trouble getting this to work with a particular non-locking modifier key, take a look at the output of `xev` when you press it, and try swapping the keycode out for `133` above (although you may need to swap out `NoSymbol` too, I don't know.)